# Call a python function from jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using jinja2, and I want to call a python function as a helper, using a similar syntax as if I were calling a macro. jinja2 seems intent on preventing me from making a function call, and insists I repeat myself by copying the function into a template as a macro.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?  And, is there any way to import a whole set of python functions and have them accessible from jinja2, without going through a whole lot of rigamarole (such as writing an extension)?

Answer (score 269):

For those using Flask, put this in your `__init__.py`:

```
def clever_function():
    return u'HELLO'

app.jinja_env.globals.update(clever_function=clever_function)
```

and in your template call it with `{{ clever_function() }}`

Comment: can you pass multiple functions like this?

Comment: In newer versions (I am using Jinja2 2.9.6) it seems to work much easier. Use the function as you would use a variable (works also in more complex situations):
`from jinja2 import Template ##newline##


def clever_function(): ##newline##
    return "Hello" ##newline##


template = Template("{{ clever_function() }}") ##newline##

print(template.render(clever_function=clever_function))`

Comment: Even 8 years later, if you're using Flask, this seems like a cleaner solution than any of the more recent answers. And to answer the old question from @ffghfgh , yes—you can pass multiple functions.

Comment: The solution from Semjon is simply brilliant. Works like a charm!

Comment: I believe this answer is nothing specific to Flask, except perhaps that the Jinja2 environment is called `app.jinja_env` ?

Comment: Nowadays there is a decorator for this for flask.app: `@app.template_global(name)`.  
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.template_global
https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/7a73171edc3bcffef96ef6367977ab3ae9af9350/src/flask/app.py#L1177

Comment: For even simpler syntax, you can also use `@app.add_template_global`. No name need be passed. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_template_global

Comment: I don't have a `__ini__.py` file but I tried to do this with a button onclick function and it did not work.
The browser console returned: "Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"

Answer (score 175):

**Note: This is Flask specific!**

I know this post is quite old, but there are better methods of doing this in the newer versions of Flask using context processors.

**Variables can easily be created:**

```
@app.context_processor
def example():
    return dict(myexample='This is an example')
```

The above can be used in a Jinja2 template with Flask like so:

```
{{ myexample }}
```

(Which outputs `This is an example`)

**As well as full fledged functions:**

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount, currency=u'€'):
        return u'{0:.2f}{1}'.format(amount, currency)
    return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

The above when used like so:

```
{{ format_price(0.33) }}
```

(Which outputs the input price with the currency symbol)

**Alternatively, you can use [jinja filters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#registering-filters), baked into Flask. E.g. using decorators:**

```
@app.template_filter('reverse')
def reverse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

Or, without decorators, and manually registering the function:

```
def reverse_filter(s):
    return s[::-1]
app.jinja_env.filters['reverse'] = reverse_filter
```

Filters applied with the above two methods can be used like this:

```
{% for x in mylist | reverse %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: where should these functions exist, init, views or just anywhere?

Comment: `__init__.py` assuming you declared `flask.Flask(__name__)` there.

Comment: Down voted as question asked about Jinja2 and answer is Flask specific.

Comment: @AJP Still theoretically answers the question. This is ONE way to solve the issue, granted you are also using Flask. A bit like all JavaScript questions often answer giving alternatives with or without jQuery or questions about Python often answer both for Python2 and 3. The question wasn't excluding Flask. (unlike a question about Py2 would exclude a Py3 answer). This answer helped me.

Comment: With Flask, you got a very easy way to add filters to Jinja! I think that's what you should be using. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#registering-filters IMHO context_processor are more about injecting data.

Comment: I've added a Jinja filter example to my answer as well, @JeromeJ. I wouldn't say that "injecting" is the correct term. You are not _pre-generating data and injecting it into the template_. Adding a context processor basically does the same thing as Jinja filters.

Comment: Very helpful, and just what I was looking for. Jinja2 is part of a web framework, and as such is not totally independent of the back-end. I work in both Django and Flask with Python and this post, as well as the others here are relevant to me. Trying to over specify a question is as harmful in my opinion as being unnecessarily vague.

Comment: In the section above titled "As well as full fledged functions:"  what is the technique for adding multiple functions (e.g. another function in addition to the format_price one?  Do you just declare them like the format_price example and also place them indented under the def utility_processor() line?

Comment: @LiamStanley How would this work where the function outputs several variables? e.g. def myfunction(): x=1, y=2, return x,y

Comment: I know this is old, but THANK YOU! This is absolutely amazing :)

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the function should be created where "app" is being instantiated. This may sound obvious, but in my case I was creating app with app = Flask(__name__) inside another function, so I had to create the utility_processor function inside the function where I was declaring app.

Answer (score 97):

I think jinja deliberately makes it difficult to run 'arbitrary' python within a template. It tries to enforce the opinion that less logic in templates is a good thing.

You can manipulate the global namespace within an `Environment` instance to add references to your functions. It must be done *before* you load any templates. For example:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def clever_function(a, b):
    return u''.join([b, a])

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('/path/to/templates'))
env.globals['clever_function'] = clever_function
```

Comment: I discovered this also -- you can add a module using something like this:  


    `import utils.helpers
    env.globals['helpers'] = utils.helpers`

Comment: @Lee. Yes, you can 'inject' namespaces (modules), functions, class instances etc. It is useful, but not as flexible as other template engines like mako. Still, jinja has other good points. I'd be grateful if you accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: did the trick for me while doing my app engine project  ( webapp2 and jinja2 ) . thanks

Comment: @RobCowie after adding the clever_function to dictionary env.globals, how can one call the function from the template.

Comment: Thus,  `{{ clever_function('a', 'b') }}`

Comment: This statement is contraction. If you can't run an arbitrary functions, you need way more logic to achieve what could have been abstracted in a function.

Answer (score 59):

```
from jinja2 import Template

def custom_function(a):
    return a.replace('o', 'ay')

template = Template('Hey, my name is {{ custom_function(first_name) }} {{ func2(last_name) }}')
template.globals['custom_function'] = custom_function
```

You can also give the function in the fields as per [Matroskin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618714/539490)

```
fields = {'first_name': 'Jo', 'last_name': 'Ko', 'func2': custom_function}
print template.render(**fields)
```

Will output:

```
Hey, my name is Jay Kay
```

Works with Jinja2 version 2.7.3

And if you want a decorator to ease defining functions on `template.globals` check out [Bruno Bronosky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291097/539490)

Comment: Probably because you downvoted everyone else's answers :(

Comment: @BorkoKovacev that's not a good reason.  I only down voted 2 answers; answers which were about Flask rather than Jinja2.  If they want to edit their answers to be on topic and about Jinja2 I will up vote them.

Comment: works perfectly once I noticed that I had over looked the `jinga_html_template.globals['custom_function'] = custom_function` line. Makes a big difference.

Comment: I made a function decorator version of this answer. It currently at the bottom with 0 votes :,-( https://stackoverflow.com/a/47291097/117471

Comment: @BrunoBronosky nice.  Have up voted :) ... give it another decade and it might be higher than mine :P ... will never catch the flasks though ;P

Answer (score 52):

I like [@AJP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27096279/117471). I used it verbatim until I ended up with a lot of functions. Then I switched to a [Python function decorator](http://programmingbits.pythonblogs.com/27_programmingbits/archive/50_function_decorators.html).

```python
from jinja2 import Template

template = '''
Hi, my name is {{ custom_function1(first_name) }}
My name is {{ custom_function2(first_name) }}
My name is {{ custom_function3(first_name) }}
'''
jinga_html_template = Template(template)

def template_function(func):
    jinga_html_template.globals[func.__name__] = func
    return func

@template_function
def custom_function1(a):
    return a.replace('o', 'ay')

@template_function
def custom_function2(a):
    return a.replace('o', 'ill')

@template_function
def custom_function3(a):
    return 'Slim Shady'

fields = {'first_name': 'Jo'}
print(jinga_html_template.render(**fields))
```

Good thing functions have a `__name__`!

Comment: This is insanely cool. When you annotate a function in python does it automatically pass the function name to the annotation's function?

Comment: @mutant_city, yep. Read that Python function decorator link. Great stuff!

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Excellent demonstration of a sensible and clean use for python decorators as well. Great post!

Comment: What a great implementation!

Comment: I'm not familiar with decorators being so simple! In every tutorial I've come across you need to define an inner function within an outer function, then call @<decorator> when do you define a function, which should be acted upon by the decorator. Insanity! This is much easier on the eyes.

Comment: @jbuddy_13 Thank you for the kind words. This is an extremely simple use case of a decorator. It's also very unconventional because the func is returned unchanged. I really only did it because I like the readability and indention of this as compared to @AJP's answer [which I originally used]. When the file got long enough to scroll, I didn't want all the `jinga_html_template.globals` additions at the bottom of the file. When I moved each to after the function it looked unpythonic. My Aspergers wouldn't let it go until it was pretty.

Comment: How can you also apply [the `@environmentfunction` decorator or similar](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#utilities)? I bet that such decorators return the function without changing its name (only setting some attributes), so you would be able to just chain the two decorators. However can you apply an `@environmentfunction` decorator from your `@template_function` decorator?

Comment: @Maëlan notice that my decorator takes and returns a function as an object and the name is (irrelevant) set later. So, I could have done `custom_function1 = template_function(custom_function1)`. That suggests that your desired decorator could be used similarly for nesting like so `return environmentalfuction(func)`. However, I'm not at a computer to try this. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ah, I am not a Python expert, but now it looks obvious! (Sorry, by “the name”, I meant “the `__name__`”.)

Answer (score 25):

Never saw such simple way at official docs or at stack overflow, but i was amazed when found this:

```
# jinja2.__version__ == 2.8
from jinja2 import Template

def calcName(n, i):
    return ' '.join([n] * i)

template = Template("Hello {{ calcName('Gandalf', 2) }}")

template.render(calcName=calcName)
# or
template.render({'calcName': calcName})
```

Comment: This answer is by far the best imho. You just pass the function to the template in exactly the same way you pass a value, after all functions are first class citizens in python :)

Answer (score 18):

There's a much simpler decision.

```
@app.route('/x')
def x():
    return render_template('test.html', foo=y)

def y(text):
    return text
```

Then, in *test.html*:

```
{{ foo('hi') }}
```

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'y' is undefined

Comment: yeah, cuz supposed to use foo in test.html

Comment: Not bad, but then you have to pass the function to every single `render_template()` call

Comment: You could create a dictionary of functions pass it instead. The dictionary could be created by writing an annotation, that saves the functions.

Answer (score 8):

To call a python function from Jinja2, you can use [custom filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#writing-filters) which work similarly as the `globals`.

It's quite simple and useful.
In a file myTemplate.txt, I wrote:

```
{{ data | pythonFct }}
```

And in a python script:

```
import jinja2

def pythonFct(data):
    return "This is my data: {0}".format(data)
    
input="my custom filter works!"
  
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path or './')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.filters['pythonFct'] = pythonFct
result = env.get_template("myTemplate.txt").render(data=input)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a lambda to connect the template to your main code

```
return render_template("clever_template", clever_function=lambda x: clever_function x)
```

Then you can seamlessly call the function in the template

```
{{clever_function(value)}}
```

Comment: Clever usage of lambda functions.

Comment: @odiumediae: No it's not. It's completely unnecessary. Just pass the function handle itself: clever_function=clever_function

Comment: @vezult I see. How could I miss that? Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 6):

is there any way to import a whole set of python functions and have them accessible from jinja2 ?

Yes there is, In addition to the other answers above, this works for me.

Create a class and populate it with the associated methods e.g

```
class Test_jinja_object:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = 'sample_var'

    def clever_function (self):
        return 'hello'
```

Then create an instance of your class in your view function and pass the resultant object to your template as a parameter for the render_template function

```
my_obj = Test_jinja_object()
```

Now in your template, you can call the class methods in jinja like so

```
{{ my_obj.clever_function () }}
```

Comment: Equivalent and slightly simpler way: put all functions for templates in a module, import that module and add it as template global.
A module is an object that contains functions :) (but not methods — no need for self param and no class reqiured!)

Comment: @ÉricAraujo What if I only need the set of functions in one or two templates and not all of them.
Also, what if I need different sets of python functions in different jinjas templates?
Would you still consider it effective to import all of them as template globals rather than put them as methods in a class and only pass the classses with the methods you need.

Comment: To use only in specific templates, I would add the functions (or a module containing functions) only to the template context dict that’s returrned by the views that use those templates.

Answer (score 5):

To import all the builtin functions you can use:

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(__builtins__)
```

Add `.__dict__` after `__builtins__` if this doesn't work.

Based on [John32323's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7226047/5445670).

Answer (score 4):

@John32323 's answer is a very clean solution.

Here is the same one, but save into a seperate file, maybe more cleaner.

#### Create helper file

*app\helper.py*

```
from app import app

def clever_function_1():
    return u'HELLO'

def clever_function_2(a, b):
    return a + b



app.jinja_env.globals.update(
    clever_function_1=clever_function_1,
    clever_function_2=clever_function_2,
)
```

#### Import from app

*app.py*

```
from app import routes
from app import helper   # add this one
```

#### Use like this

*app\templates\some.html*

```
{{ clever_function_1() }}
{{ clever_function_2(a, b) }}
```

Comment: The elegance of this solution is astounding. Good job. I only define the functions in the `app.py` file and then there are no ugly imports.

Answer (score 4):

For those using FastApi, put this in your `__init__.py`:

```py
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

def clever_function():
    return u'HELLO'

templates.env.globals.update(clever_function=clever_function)
```

and in your template call it with `{{ clever_function() }}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it with Django, you can just pass the function with the context:

```
context = {
    'title':'My title',
    'str': str,
}
...
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Now you will be able to use the `str` function in jinja2 template

Answer (score 1):

```
Creating a global function without passing to the template

@app.template_global('double')
def double(n):
    return 2 * n

Jinja Usage`enter code here`

{{double(77)}}

Or
Creating a filter in jinja.


@app.template_filter('geo_stuff')
def hellome(a,b='dadadd'):
    d=a+'it is jerry'
    return d
jinja use
{{'foo'|geo_stuff}}
```