# Jinja2 Template - for loop

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

didn't find another post which has the similar problem, I'm trying to generate some checkboxes with flask and wtforms, at the moment I've got this piece of code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <p><strong>Check the enabled BRI Ports</strong></p>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        {{ form.bri1(value=1) }} {{ form.bri1.label }}
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        {{ form.bri2(value=1) }} {{ form.bri2.label }}
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        {{ form.bri3(value=1) }} {{ form.bri3.label }}
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        {{ form.bri4(value=1) }} {{ form.bri4.label }}
    </label>
</div>
```

This works so far, but now I try to do this with a simple for-loop like:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <p><strong>Check the enabled BRI Ports</strong></p>
    {% for n in range(1,6) %}
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        {{ form.brin.label }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I tried with (), {} and {{}} ... is this even possible?

Comment: This is not a question about Flask, because Flask doesn't include a template engine. Presumably you are asking about Jinja2?

Comment: Sorry my fault, you're totaly right.

Comment: @Kilrathy So the problem is with "range"? Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6036082/1205368) helps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <p><strong>Check the enabled BRI Ports</strong></p>
    {% for name, field in form._fields.items() %}
        {% if name != 'csrf_token' %}
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                {{ field(value=1) }} {{ field.label }}
            </label>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

There you can set sorting instead `form._fields.items()` or condition instead `{% if name != 'csrf_token' %}`. Or:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <p><strong>Check the enabled BRI Ports</strong></p>
    {% for n in range(1,6) %}
        {% if form['bri' + n|string] %}
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                {{ form['bri' + n|string](value=1) }} {{ form['bri' + n|string].label }}
            </label>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

There you can also use `n.__str__()` instead filter `n|string`.

Comment: I tried both, the second one gives me the error "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". The fist one partially works, but it gives me all field out, I only want the BooleanField bri1-4... any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I updated second example. For first you can add own condition: `{% if name.startswith('bri') %}`.