# Custom parameter in Flask-WTFoms field

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

***forms.py***

```
my_field = TextField(u"Enter a number", validators=[Required('This Field is Required')])
```

***my_form.html***

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"> 
      {{form.my_field(placeholder= form.my_field.label.text, class_="form-control")}}
      {% for error in form.my_field.errors %}
          <span>{{error}}</span>
      {% endfor %}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is a simple code. But I want to follow kind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687520/jinja2-template-for-loop) to render all the input fields in a loop instead of writing the code for each of them. But each field will have a different `colspan` value in the corresponding `<td>`.

How can I add a custom parameter for colspan which I can use in the `<td>`?

Something like: (just the `diff` from above code)

***forms.py***

```
my_field = TextField(colspan="4")
```

***my_form.html***

```
<td colspan={{form.my_field.colspan}}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [custom field](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#custom-fields) with an extra `colspan` attribute.

First define the custom field sub classing `TextField`:

```
class MyCustomTextField(TextField):
    def __init__(self, colspan=4, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomTextField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.colspan = colspan
```

Now use the custom field in your form:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    my_field = MyCustomTextField(4, u"Enter a number", validators=[Required('This Field is Required')])
```

See that first parameter (a `4` in this case) for `MyCustomTextField`? That's your colspan attribute.

Finally, access the attribute in your template like so:

```
<td colspan="{{form.my_field.colspan}}">
```

Comment: This custom class is a good idea which I always forget. But in this case, I need to create a common custom class for all the fields. Not just the `TextField` as in my case I've more than 20 form fields with nearly all types of input fields available out there. Is it possible to create something like that?

Comment: That's a tough one. I have been messing around for a while trying to sub class the parent `Field` class and then trying to change the parent class of other fields grabbing some ideas from this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541560/3632543

But I wasn't successful at it, plus it is mentioned it is not really a good idea to do. The easiest (although I understand is kinda clumsy) way to do this would be to just define your own set of fields, sub classing each field you need. I know it's quite a bit of code to write but should be a one time job and pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yeah. It will be a one time job only and can use it in future usage also. Thanks.