# Print the last modification of a jinja2 template in pelican

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I am using Pelican 3.3 and I have an *almost* static file `index.html` in my jinja2 templates. I would like to display the date of the last modification of the file within it.

I found quite easily that `article.locale_date` and `page.locale_date` are doing the job for articles and pages (with `DEFAULT_DATE = 'fs'`). But, I cannot figure out how to do this for a template file.

I found [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2) about using a Python function through other Python modules such as `Flask` or `Environment`. But, is there a simpler way to get the date of last modification of a template file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a dirty trick, so I still hope that somebody will answer this question in a more nicer way than I did.

The point is to use the `pelicanconf.py` file to set up an environment variable to get the required date. I just added the following to `pelicanconf.py`:

```
import os.path, time
INDEX_DATE = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(path/to/the/index.html))
```

Once you get the `INDEX_DATE` variable set, you can use it in your Jinja2 templates like this:

```
{{ INDEX_DATE }}
```

So, this is a quick and dirty trick. Hopefully, somebody will give me a better way !

Comment: perror, it works, if user specify the path to a single file (`path/to/the/index.html` in example). But is it possible print last modification for each article? Can user pass `article` as argument? Thanks.