# How to handle attribute access errors in Jinja2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I've got this:

```
template = '{{invoice.customer.address.city}}'
```

And it works fine. But sometimes `invoice.customer is Null or invoice.customer.address is Null` and then jinja throws `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'address'` because it can't reach that `.city` part. So how do I tell it to just fail silently if it can't access an attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this frequently, rather than creating a per-attribute
filter you could generalize Vor's answer to work for arbitrary nested
dictionaries, like this:

```
import jinja2

def filter_nested_dict(value, default, path):
    keys = path.split('.')
    for key in keys:
        try:
            value = value[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    return value


env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters['nested_dict'] = filter_nested_dict

template = env.from_string('''
  City: {{invoice|nested_dict('<none>', 'customer.address.city')}}''')
```

Given the above, this:

```
print template.render(invoice={})
```

Gives you:

```
City: <none>
```

And this:

```
print template.render(invoice={'customer': {'address': {'city': 'boston'}}})
```

Gives you:

```
City: boston
```

Comment: Yes, that's much better but still too cumbersome. That {{invoice|nested_dict('<none>', 'customer.address.city')}}''') is an instant no-go - the template will become unreadable.

Comment: I'll admit that I don't see much of a difference in readability between this one and what you've proposed, but I'm glad you've found a solution that works for you.

Comment: You are right, my solution is not that much more readable then yours, but it has another advantage - it handles callables. With arguments. Which is a good thing :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a custom filter and pass the whole `invoice` object to it rather then trying to find workarounds in Jinja.

For example:

```
import jinja2 


def get_city_from_invoice(invoice):
  try:
      return invoice['customer']['address']['city']
  except KeyError:
      return None

env = jinja2.Environment()
env.filters['get_city_from_invoice'] = get_city_from_invoice

d = {'invoice': {'customer': {'address': {'city': 'foo'}}}}
d1 = {'invoice': {'no-customers': 1 }}

print "d: ", env.from_string('{{ invoice | get_city_from_invoice }}').render(d)
print "d1: ", env.from_string('{{ invoice | get_city_from_invoice }}').render(d1)
```

Will print:

```
d:  foo
d1:  None
```

Comment: You are proposing to write a custom filter for each case? A simple invoice template would require a dozen of them!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it. The answer seems to be in using globals, like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2/6038550#6038550)

So I've tried to build on that, and the result was this:

```
def jinja_global_eval(c, expr):
    """Evaluates an expression. Param c is data context"""
    try:
        return str(eval(expr))
    except:
        return ''
```

After installing this into my template environment with `templating_env.globals['eval'] = jinja_global_eval` I now can do this in my templates:

```
{{eval(invoice, 'c.customer.address.city')}}
```

and this:

```
{{eval(invoice, 'c.customer.get_current_balance()')}}
```

It will probably bite my pants during debugging, but to avoid it a simple logging could be installed into `jinja_global_eval`. Anyways, thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It needs further testing as it might break things, but what about extending the
`Environment` class and override the gettatr (or getitem) method like this

```
from jinja2 import Environment

class SEnvironment(Environment):
    ERROR_STRING = 'my_error_string'
    def getattr(self, obj, attribute):
        """Get an item or attribute of an object but prefer the attribute.
                Unlike :meth:`getitem` the attribute *must* be a bytestring.
                """
        try:
            return getattr(obj, attribute)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            return obj[attribute]
        except (TypeError, LookupError, AttributeError):
            return SEnvironment.ERROR_STRING # this lines changes
```

then if you want to handle errors you can create filters like `raise_error` or `dislay_error`

```
def raise_error(obj):
    if obj == SEnvironment.ERROR_STRING:
        raise Exception('an error occured')
    return obj
        

def print_error(obj, _str='other error'):
    if obj == SEnvironment.ERROR_STRING:
        return _str
    return obj

jinja_env = SEnvironment()
jinja_env.filters['raise_error'] = raise_error
jinja_env.filters['print_error'] = print_error
jinja_env = jinja_env.from_string("""{{ test1.test2.test3 }}""") # -> my_error_string
#jinja_env = jinja_env.from_string("""{{ test1.test2.test3|print_error('<none>') }}""") # -> <none>
#jinja_env = jinja_env.from_string("""{{ test1.test2.test3|raise_error }}""") # -> Exception: an error occured
res = jinja_env.render({
    'test1': {
        'test2': None
    }
})
```