# escape dot in variable names in jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I have jinja template file with variable names like x.y.z (like java package names). Then I'm using Python envtpl to generate actual config file from jinja template file using envtpl.process_file. But it errors out saying 'x' is undefined. I know in jinja dot means something else so how do I escape it so that envtpl understands that 'x.y.z' is a variable name not just 'x'.

template file for example:

```
foo = "{{ x.y.z | default("abc") }}"
bar = "{{ a.b.c | default("123") }}"
```

Comment: A Jinja template needs a context to be rendered with. How do you define it?

Comment: I am not using Jinja directly so not sure how do I define that. I'm using this Python library : https://github.com/andreasjansson/envtpl for generating a file from a template.

Comment: So your context is your environment. A dot is not allowed in environmental variable names. Can you give a example of your environment?

Comment: Create a global function like this {% get_var(x, y, z) %} More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I couldn't find good solution, so now I convert dot in my variables name to underscore before passing them to envtpl.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still interested in this, this worked for me:

```
/* model */
...
some_function('some.value')
...



{# macro #}
{% macro some_function(value) %}
    {% set data = {{ "'"+value+"'" }} %}
    {{ data }}
{% endmacro %}
```

OR

```
{# macro #}
{% macro some_function(value) %}
    {% set data = {{ "'%s'" % value }} %}
    {{ data }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping it with [single quotes](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#escaping) worked for me inside of conditionals.
For example:

```
{% if 'x.y.z' is defined -%}
```