# How can I return multi-column table row values for a url_for using the Jinja2 iterrows function?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In the example below, I'm creating href's for each row item in Column3 and the variable (var1) will be sent along with it (which works fine).  My question is how can I also send the adjacent row value using a variable (var2) for Column1?   Would this need to be handled with jquery or another means?

var2 below is what what I want to be able to do, but not sure how to, currently.

table:

```
       Column1    Column2    Column3
Row1   Yes        Foo        Bar 
Row2   No         Foo1       Bar3
Row3   Maybe      Foo2       Bar2
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/mypage/<var1>')
def python_function(var1,var2):
    df = pd.DataFrame(lotsofdata)
    return render_template('index.html',data=df)
```

index.html:

```
<table id="data">
<thead>
<tr>
{% for c in data.columns.values %}
    <th>{{ c }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for index, row in data.iterrows() %}
    <tr>
        {% for v in row %}
            <td>
            {% if data.columns[loop.index0] in ['Column3'] %}
                <a href="{{ url_for('python_function',var1=v,var2=???) }}">{{ v }}</a>
            {% else %}
                {{ v }}
            {% endif %}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To call a function you'd do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7226047/6085135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function in jinja you'd create a global function in **__init__.py**

```
def cool_func(var1, var2):
    return var1 + var2  # or something

app.jinja_env.globals.update(cool_func=cool_func)
```

Then for you example you could replace:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('python_function',var1=v,var2=???) }}">
```

With:

```
<a href={{ cool_func(var1, var2) }}>
```

Comment: Ahhh.. I hadn't thought about doing it this way.  Identify the adjacent cell in python and then call call it from jinja... that makes multi-cell calls super easy now.  Fantastic, thank you!