# How can I use and call a python function within HTML while using Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to Flask and even though I have read through the documentation, I am still very confused on the relationship between Python functions and HTML. Specifically, I am unsure of how a function can be called within an HTML page. For example, I have the following code on my route.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/placement_debugger')
def placementDebugger():
    return render_template('placement_debugger.html')
def get_data():
    return requests.get('http://example.com'+placementID).content
```

Here is the code from my "placement_debugger.html" file. Basically, I am trying to obtain an ID from a user and use that ID within an HTTP GET request:

```
<p1>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <strong>Placement ID: </strong><input type="text" name="Placement ID" 
     value=""><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</p1>
```

How can I call my "get_data()" function within the "placement_debugger.html" page?

Comment: You can't directly do that. You CAN make a REST call to the get_data() function from Javascript from your web page and get the return data. The Python code runs on the web server, and the HTML runs on the client's machine -- they can only communicate via HTTP -- a stateless protocol.

Comment: Please notice that `render_template()` accepts additional keyword arguments as context. This is the way to pass data (not functions) to the template.

Comment: You could do that with Jinja2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2. But I dont recommend using this solution at all in your case. Better passing variables through `render_template()` as Klaus said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request` to get the data from your HTML inputs.

First import it from flask

```
from flask import request
```

By default Flask only allows `GET` requests. You'll need to allow `POST` methods to your route.

```
@app.route('/placement_debugger', methods=['GET', 'POST')
```

Here is how you can get the data from the HMTL form. (This would go in your get_data() function)

```
if request.form:
    placement_id = request.form.get('Placement ID')
```