# Using "if any():" in Jinja2?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

In Jinja2 I'm looking for a way to check if at least one of a list of variables has a value. Basically in python I would do:

```
if any([item['genre'], item['type'], item['color']]):
```

However, in Jinja the following isn't valid:

```
{% if any([item['genre'], item['type'], item['color']]) %}
# some part of the Jinja template
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to have the same "any()" check in Jinja2?

For background: the full piece of code that I currently try to add (but isn't valid):

```
{% if any([item['genre'], item['type'], item['color']]) %}
<ItemProperties>
    <ItemProperty key="genre">{{ item['genre'] }}</ItemProperty>
    <ItemProperty key="type">{{ item['type'] }}</ItemProperty>
    <ItemProperty key="color">{{ item['color'] }}</ItemProperty>
</ItemProperties>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: For 3 hardcoded entries, why not just use `if item['genre'] or item['type'] or item['color']`? Jinja2 is Python-*like*, not Python itself, there is no `any()`.

Comment: `any(item['genre'], item['type'], item['color'])` -> `any` accepts only one argument, so that wouldn't work even in plain Python

Comment: @ForceBru: I think we can still work out what is being asked, though.

Comment: built-in functions are not available in jinja2, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2 - you have to pass it to global enviroment somehow, I dont use it so I might be wrong

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik: that post is about registering a function; this is really a *filter*, so my answer below shows how to register `any()` and `all()`.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah that was a typo, forgot the squared brackets for the list. 
Edited.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters `any` and `all` are python functions from module `builtins` you can register them the same way

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik: yes, I didn't say you couldn't. I'm saying that there is a better option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no *direct* equivalent of the `any()` function in Jinja2 templates.

For 3 hard-coded elements, I'd just use [boolean logic `or`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#logic):

```html
{% if item['genre'] or item['type'] or item['color'] %}
```

Otherwise, you can use the [`select()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select) without an argument (followed by [`first()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.first) to force iteration). Because `select()` is itself a generator, using `first()` on `select()` makes this short-circuit the way `any()` would:

```html
{% if (item['genre'], item['type'], item['color'])|select|first %}
```

Without an argument, `select()` returns any objects from the input sequence that are true, and `first()` ensures it iterates no more than needed to find one such element.

The last option is to [register a custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#custom-filters) to just add `any()` to Jinja yourself; I'd also add `all()` in that case. You can register both functions *directly*, since neither takes options:

```
environment.filters['any'] = any
environment.filters['all'] = all
```

at which point you can then use

```html
{% if (item['genre'], item['type'], item['color'])|any %}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters question asked for Jinja2, so this is not necessarily interesting, but since this is the first thing coming up when googling for use of any in Jinja it might still be good to add:


Jinja3 has a reject filter, with which one might simulate any `if any(value not in list for value in values)` becomes `if values | reject("in", some_list) | first`.
Maybe not the best example, but worked for me.
[The docs.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reject)

Comment: @Fynn: basically, `reject` is the inverse of `select`, the implementation for these filters uses a [single `select_or_reject()` function](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/86f28a9df0a97a3d3bfa3785b082651e2a8e994d/src/jinja2/filters.py#L1757-L1770) with a different `modfunc` callable that is returns either `value` or `not value`. It's not unique to Jinja 3, both `select` and `reject` were [added in version 2.7](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-2-7).