# Call function with arguments from user input in Python3 Flask Jinja2 template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am writing a web application which accepts user input in an HTML form written in Jinja2.
Based on the input, I set variables defined in Jinja2 which I then want to pass as positional arguments to another function defined in either my `__init__.py` file or `main.py` file.

```
Python version==3.6.8  
Flask==2.0.1  
Jinja2==3.0.1
```

I attempted many ways to achieve this but could not so (got an undefined error when trying to call the function), including following the suggestions in this thread: [Call a python function from jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2)

The file structure of my web app looks like so:
https://prntscr.com/1rlt3cl (I can't post images because I don't have enough reputation points so I uploaded it here).

I am receiving user input in my `form.html` file which I pass to the `data.html` file.

```
<form action="/data" method = "POST">
    <p>Various inputs<input type = "number" name = "random" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

From the `data.html` file, I want to accept the values inputted by the user, and call a function which sits in all of my `__init__.py` files (wasn't sure which one Flask actually looks at):

```
{% set ns1 = namespace(random=None) %}   
{% for key,value in form_data.items() %}
    {% if key ==  "iterations" %}
        {%- set ns1.iterations = value -%}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ clever_function(random) }}
```

clever_function is defined in the `__init__.py` file as so:

```
from jinja2 import Template 
def clever_function(): 
    return "Hello"
    
template = Template("{{ clever_function() }}")
template.globals['clever_function'] = clever_function
```

When running my application from `webapp/main.py` which renders the form / data templates like so:

```
@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')
 
@app.route('/data', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return f"The URL /data is accessed directly. Try going to '/form' to submit form"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = request.form
        return render_template('data.html',form_data = form_data)
```

I receive the following exception:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'clever_function' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you use is a brief description of the exclusive use within a directly defined template.
To use a custom function within a template used by `render_template`, you have to add it to the dictionary globals of the jinja environment.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request

def clever_function(value):
    return value**2

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(clever_function=clever_function)

@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    return render_template('data.html', form_data=request.form)
```

From now on, this function can be called in every template which is loaded and called up with this environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Result: {{ clever_function(form_data.get('random', 0) | int) }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that the defined function must accept parameters if you want to call it up with any.

---

Errors have also crept in when using the namespace object. You should take another look at the documentation for the assignments in jinja2.

Here is a small example based on your code.

```
{% set ns1 = namespace(random=0) %}
{% for k,v in form_data.items() %}
  {% if k == 'random' %}
    {% set ns1.random = v | int %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<p>Value is {{ns1.random}}</p>
```