# Override (overwrite) macro with Flask context processor?

Tags: python, flask

Suppose I want to override a Jinja macro with a function defined in `routes.py` that returns `None`. I attempted to use a Context Processor (`@app.context_processor`) but it didn’t override the macro. (It outputs the assignment made in `macros.html`.)

routes.py

```python
@app.context_processor
def thing():
        def my_macro():
                return None
    return dict(my_macro=my_macro)
```

macros.html

```python
{% macro my_macro() %}Arbitrary_text{% endmacro %}
```

The reason I am doing this is so I can add some conditional datetime logic using python (instead of writing it in Jinja).

Context Processor documentation is here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/templating/#context-processors

Answer (score 0):

You still have to remove import calls made to `my_macro` in your templates (and remove {# or comment out #} the definition in `macros.html`) but the following will work:

```python
@app.add_template_global
def my_macro():
    return None
```

For more: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_template_global,

[Call a python function from jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2#comment120845134_7226047)